# beginner php/mysql => add data to DB from HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

im trying to add data into my database using the data that the user inputs into an html form. Here's my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn = new mysqli(/* private infos hidden on stackoverflow */);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {

    $getName = $_POST['name'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO data ('name') VALUES ('$getName')";

    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>

<html>

<form method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton">
</form>

</html>
```

i get this error:

> Error: INSERT INTO data ('name') VALUES ('', '', '', '', '')
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''name') VALU' at line 1

** WHAT I ALREADY TRIED: **

- "INSERT INTO data ('name') VALUES ('$getName')";
- "INSERT INTO data ('name') VALUES ($getName)";
- "INSERT INTO data (name) VALUES ('$getName')";
- "INSERT INTO 'data' ('name') VALUES ('$getName')";
- "INSERT INTO data (name) VALUES ($getName)";
- "INSERT INTO data (name) VALUES '$getName'";

thanks for any help guys

Comment: Since you are just learning, you might want to start with prepared statements now (before you learn the wrong way to run queries and need to re-learn it).  The way you are trying to run a query is *extremely* unsafe and is just asking for SQL injection attacks.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  See also: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Why does your error message show `VALUES ('', '', '', '', '')`?  What *exactly* are you entering into this input field?  If you are just entering in a name, then this error makes no sense!

Comment: Name is a reserved word. Use backticks

Comment: It's just a keyword, not a reserved one, so ticks aren't needed. But doesn't hurt either!

Comment: *"Name is a reserved word. Use backticks"* - No, `name` is not a reserved word, it's a "keyword" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - Two different animals here.

Comment: As @RocketHazmat stated; for what you posted for code and the error, "it never happened".

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `data` (`name`) VALUES ('$getName')";
```

Edit: Forgot about the backticks arround data keyword.

Comment: *"Forgot about the backticks arround data keyword."* - They're only a "keyword" and not a reserved word - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - So there's no need to tick that. They had regular quotes rather than ticks or none at all.

Answer (score -1):

Or

```
INSERT INTO data (name)
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO data (`name`)
```

upd.: The words "name" and "data" are reserved in SQL and use them as table and field names is a bad idea.

Comment: What this answer is trying to say is that the column name (and table name) need to wrapped in *backticks*, not single quotes.

Comment: *"The words "name" and "data" are reserved in SQL"* - No they're not reserved words, they're "keywords" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - Two different animals here.

Comment: In the context _reserved words_ == _keywords_ (:

Answer (score -2):

INSERT INTO data ('name') VALUES ('', '', '', '', '') -> how many columns do you have in that particular table ? 5 ? if so, you need to look into the doc -> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)